# Vue router.beforeEach doesn't fire components update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm making a loader for my vue app toggling through router.beforeEach and router.afterEach to router.preloaderActive variable. Then in component I "v-if" preloader by this var. afterEach works just fine, but component won't detect this.$router.preloaderActive change made by router.beforeEach.

```
app.js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    router.preloaderActive = true; // doesn't work 'cause component won't update
    return next();
});

router.afterEach( (to, from) => {
    router.preloaderActive = false;
});
```

```
app.vue
<transition name="fade">
   <div class="_loader" v-if="$router.preloaderActive">
       <i class="fa fa-gear fa-spin"></i>
   </div>
</transition>
```

**EDIT:** Problem is, that beforeEach() doesn't trigger update on components, so component won't detect change of variable. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you mean the current component won't start loading, or the next one?
Also, it is not needed to return next(), simply doing `next()` does the job just as fine

Comment: Everything works fine, just component will not detect change of this.$router.preloaderActive when beforeEach() changes it. It will detect only change of it made by afterEach()

Comment: Maybe it is not being reactive due to router not having this key by default?
you could try to set it via `Vue.set(router, 'preloaderActive', true)` instead of `router.preloaderActive = true;`

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. It's like there's no component update event triggered when router.beforeEach is done.

Comment: `vm.$nextTick()` - to wait for component changes.